# Intellitest mocking issue

Tags: pex, intellitest

I have a situation like this right now. On the below code I am running visual studio Intellitest, However I am able to mock the classes A and B using fake assembly and able to run the explorations. But when it comes to the constructor of B class where PEX is trying to instantiate a Concrete class on the constructor level class B and subsequently trying to invoke a function(ie  _c.CMethod()). In this scenario Pex is throwing  run time warning "unable to instrument the methods" and aborting the code exploration by leaving code coverage to minimum. I am following this [article](http://[1]:%20http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521004/White-box-testing-with-PEX) for mocking complex objects.

Sample code

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IB _IB;
    public A(IB IntfB)
    {
        _IB = IntfB;
    }

    public void Amethod()
    {
        _IB.CallingBMethod();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        C _c = new C();
        _c.CMethod();
    }

    public string CallingBMethod()
    {
        return "Return from BMethod";
    }
}

public interface IB
{
    string CallingBMethod();
}

    enter code here

public class C
{
    public string CMethod()
    {
        return "Return from CMethod";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me some more about which types did you fake? Which method are you exploring with IntelliTest?

In the meantime, please refer the content here: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/developer-testing/intellitest-manual/index.

Comment: Hi, Here I am trying to instantiate the class C and invoking method inside the constructor of class B ie  "_c.CMethod()". Which is resulting in  warning "unable to instrument the methods". and also does pex exploration works on Entity Framework methods?

Comment: I don't quite follow. The hyperlink to the article seems broken. Can you please point me to that article? I will take a look.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable time. Here is the article "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521004/White-box-testing-with-PEX".